# OData filter is not working in my web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, odata

I didn't create OData controller, instead, I just installed OData package and add EnableQuery attribute to the IQueryable action method. Here is my method

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("WoundLocations")]
    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<WoundLocation> GetWoundArea()
    {
        return _lookupService.GetWoundLocation().AsQueryable();
    }
```

And I call the action with the following url

```
  http://dev-xxx.xxxx.com/lookup/WoundLocations?filter=Side eq '0'
```

The returned result still has all the records in that table. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a `$` before the `filter` keyword, it should be like this:

```
http://dev-xxx.xxxx.com/lookup/WoundLocations?$filter=Side eq '0'
```

Comment: You are right. but after I added '$', the returned result is not right. so I use http://dev-xxx.xxxx.com/lookup/WoundLocations?$filter=Side eq 3, but it returns nothing. however, if I use Side eq 1 it returns some value. I queried from DB, it has lots of records that Side equals to 3

Comment: That sounds like a different issue, probably around the implementation of the `_lookupService.GetWoundLocation()` method. Maybe post another question if you can't work that part out - it may not even be anything to do with OData! :)